# how to get the median of each pairs of rows with interval

Tags: r

I have a data which looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), grp = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), `02` = c(36034L, 63763L, 51432L, 65100L, 61444L, 
71012L, 266610L, 389787L, 47659L, 63156L, 84593L, 84331L), `03` = c(45632L, 
66505L, 60360L, 36685L, 107551L, 53360L, 323952L, 344944L, 69601L, 
51268L, 130665L, 59704L), `04` = c(59025L, 52837L, 68571L, 35788L, 
75262L, 66601L, 424683L, 340948L, 79487L, 42809L, 95607L, 81739L
), `05` = c(74767L, 48210L, 70972L, 67705L, 85576L, 89265L, 393380L, 
306633L, 77816L, 73611L, 106317L, 116890L), `06` = c(50846L, 
37970L, 63896L, 78296L, 81216L, 62308L, 62613L, 21770L, 80955L, 
88832L, 97586L, 68345L), `07` = c(26688L, 27830L, 17010L, 54074L, 
26727L, 31109L, 24448L, 38701L, 17378L, 46327L, 25324L, 25325L
), `08` = c(16498L, 26604L, 41201L, 38417L, 43709L, 33217L, 69943L, 
80638L, 37444L, 31701L, 46781L, 31152L), `09` = c(16272L, 24485L, 
14546L, 74756L, 28193L, 770L, 72238L, 78418L, 9161L, 48618L, 
26466L, 1078L), `10` = c(20612L, 713L, 18114L, 57872L, 25684L, 
27985L, 73618L, 1770L, 11953L, 33347L, 25824L, 25860L), `11` = c(23549L, 
856L, 32854L, 42906L, 33385L, 26218L, 88509L, 62103L, 23377L, 
29738L, 33504L, 26642L)), .Names = c("time", "grp", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11"), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to get the median of the first two rows , then the second two rows ... but it is not that easy

I want to get the median of two rows, when the time is 1 and the grp is A and B (for column 3 to 6).

Then get the average of when the time is 1 and the grep is C and D (for column 3 to 6)

then get the average of when the time is 1 and the grep is E and F (for the column of 3 to 6)

Then do the same for when the time is 5 or whatever time is there

I thought it could be done using apply by first ignoring the column 1 and 2 `df[,-c(1,2)]` then using row `1` then through tapply based on column 1 which I don't know how to proceed

```
apply(df[,-c(1,2)], 1, function(x) tapply(x, df[,1], median))
```

If I do this , it gives me two values which is not good

```
apply(df[1:2,3:6], 1, median)
      1       2 
52328.5 58300.0
```

I try to make an example output

an expected output is like below (I used Median function in xls for this)

```
time    median  2 to 5  6 to 7  8 to 11
1        A,B    55931   32900   18555
1        C,D    62730   58985   39809
1        E,F    73137   46708.5 28089
5        A,B    342946  184623  72928
5        C,D    66378.5 63641   30719.5
5        E,F    90100   46835   26554
```

Time is clear

median shows between what rows

2 to 5 is the median of column 2, 3 ,4 and 5

6 to 7 is the median of column 6 and 7

8 to 11 is the median of column 8, 9, 10, and 11

Comment: Could you provide the desired output?

Comment: do you mean average or median??

Comment: @Onyambu does not matter. one can use mean or median , I made an example output above

Comment: @Joseph Wood  I made an example output above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a splitting factor that will be used to split the data into 2 rows: I used a general view here. But for this data you can do `rep(1:nrow(dat),each=2)` Although I included other things so as to generalize the code.

Then using this manipulate your data as follows:

```
 splitfactor=rep(1:ceiling(nrow(dat)),each=2,length=nrow(dat))
 dataused=list(3:6,7:8,9:12)
 grp=do.call(rbind,by(dat[1:2],splitfactor,function(x) cbind(x[1,1],paste0(x[,2],collapse = ","))))  
 medians=sapply(dataused,function(x)by(dat[,x],splitfactor,function(m)median(unlist(m))))
 data.frame(grp,medians)
      X1  X2     X3.6    X7.8   X9.12
    1  1 A,B  55931.0 32900.0 18555.0
    2  1 C,D  62730.0 58985.0 39809.0
    3  1 E,F  73137.0 46708.5 28089.0
    4  5 A,B 342946.0 31574.5 72928.0
    5  5 C,D  66378.5 63641.0 30719.5
    6  5 E,F  90100.0 46835.0 26554.0
```

Comment: @nik You are asked to search for earlier questions that might address questions. I think most people here would be rightly annoyed if they got a good answer to a question and then were denied a checkmark because you decide to ask for material not in the body of the question and arguably unrelated code.